# Reading from SQL SELECT in using Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I have been looking for the issue which I couldn't figure out. Need help.
Below is the powershell script that is used to revoke the Public rrights on available media. I am trying to check the result of my SQL query and then returning the result for the same in the powershell variable sNumCountAvailMed but whenever the reader reads the information it always give me the Fieldcount as 1 and doesn't give any other result . Please let me know what am I doing wrong in below Command. I am trying to read the sql reader during the debug and most of the time it return no value and this go out of loop

## System defined variables

```
[string] $Server= $sStrSQLName
[string] $Database = "master"
$SQLQuery= @"
DECLARE @sNumCountAvailMed INT
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_permissions WHERE OBJECT_NAME(major_id) = 'xp_availablemedia' AND [type] = 'EX')
BEGIN
REVOKE EXECUTE ON xp_availablemedia TO PUBLIC;
END
SELECT @sNumCountAvailMed = count(*) FROM sys.database_permissions WHERE OBJECT_NAME(major_id) = 'xp_availablemedia' AND [type] = 'EX'
SELECT @sNumCountAvailMed
"@


    try
    {
        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
        $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
        $Connection.Open()
        $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
        $Command.Connection = $Connection
        $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
        $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
        Write-Host $Reader.VisibleFieldCount       
        while ($Reader.Read()) {
             Write-Host $Reader.GetValue($1)
        }
        $Connection.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first problem is here:

```
$Reader.GetValue($1)
```

GetValue() takes a single int, and $1 isn't an int.  Did you mean :

```
$Reader.GetValue(1)
```

And...you probably mean 0 instead of 1...

Comment: Yes that would be the second problem ,but the main problem is the debugger doesn't go inside the while loop . The reader returns null value and sometime with value ad FieldCount = 1 but in both cases the debugger fails to go inside the while loop.